# script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have checked all the available solution but didn't help me to resolve the problem.
I have simple code but it fails to run with the mentioned error.

Here is my code

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="piApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="system.js@*" data-semver="0.16" src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script> 
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body data-ng-controller="piController">
    <div class="container-

fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h1> Dash Board</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div 

class="col-xs-12">
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="item in data">
               

 <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.value}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="form-group">
    

        <button data-ng-="" click="getControllPanel()" class="btn btn-primary">Control Panel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the script.js

```js
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('piApp',[]);

app.controller("piController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = 

    [{
      name: "Temperature",
      value: 25
    }, 
    {
      name: "Humidity",
      value: 75
    },
    {
      name: "Humidity2",
      value: 75
    }];
}]);
```

Not able to understand what is causing the mentioned error?
Do I need to have the angular.min.js locally?
Am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added dependency of angular2, and you have written code of angularjs
Also, you cannot use "data-ng-app" before loading the script. So remove it from html tag, and add it in body.

Add following line in head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
```

and remove the first two lines which has dependency of systemjs and angular2

Comment: Thanks Manish. I have moved data-ng-app from <html> to <body> now. Still the problem exists. Any idea?

Comment: as I mentioned, you are using the angular 2 dependency in your code.
Updated the answer.

Comment: this worked. I missed that angularjs portion. Thank you.